# Access parent class method through child instance

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class Organ():
    def __init__(self, organ_name, organ_weight):
        self.organ_name = organ_name
        self.organ_weight = organ_weight
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "The {organ}'s weight is {weight}"\
        .format(organ=self.organ_name, weight = self.organ_weight) 

class Heart(Organ):
    def __init__(self, heart_weight):
        self.heart_weight_grams = heart_weight
        super().__init__(__class__.__name__, self.heart_weight_grams)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "My heart's weight is {weight} grams"\
        .format(weight=self.heart_weight_grams)

my_heart = Heart(200)
print(my_heart) #returns "My heart's weight is 200 grams"
```

From my child instance `my_heart`, how do I access the parent class method `__repr__()` method?

Comment: what do you mean "from my child instance", *exactly*?

Answer (score 2):

To access the parent from child use `super()`, ie : `super().__repr__()` but here you don't need it, in fact you may **not** use  `heart_weight_grams` attribut, because it's the same as `organ_weight` in the parent

If you have more attributs into `Heart` class, you can call `__repr__` parent and concat more info from the child class

```
class Organ:
    def __init__(self, organ_name, organ_weight):
        self.organ_name = organ_name
        self.organ_weight = organ_weight

    def __repr__(self):
        return "The {organ}'s weight is {weight}".format(organ=self.organ_name, weight=self.organ_weight)
        # return f"The {self.organ_name}'s weight is {self.organ_weight}" # shorter 
    
class Heart(Organ):
    def __init__(self, heart_weight, hearbeat=60):
        super(Heart, self).__init__("heart", heart_weight)
        self.hearbeat = hearbeat

    def __repr__(self):
        return super().__repr__() + f" and beats at {self.hearbeat}"

my_heart = Heart(200)
print(my_heart)  # The Heart's weight is 200
```

Comment: sorry the class architecture was given as per my assignment instructions. My assignment instructed me to add a repr method for both organ and heart and also certain attributes for organ and heart. But for my original question, how do i access the parent's repr method from my child instance?

Comment: I wouldn't do: `__class__.__name__`. If this is necessary, the name should be an explicit attribute. Relying on the class name itself is a bad practice. You should be free to refactor the class name without breaking something like that.

Comment: @CrazyCoder As I wrote `super().__repr__()`

Comment: @CrazyCoder Look, i've add the child adding info to the parent repr

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit a class, you can access parent functions using `super`. Just use `super().__repr__()` to access the function.

Comment: nitpick: `super` is not a keyword